# How to show all running launchctl daemons/agents?

Tags: macos, launchd

When I run:

```
sudo launchctl bslist
```

... it shows all the running /System daemons, but I have some running from `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and it is not showing those.

How can I show them all?

Comment: bslist lists "Mach bootstrap services " and so I think not all daemons - launchctl list shows more

Comment: Yes, "sudo launchctl list" shows them all. Thanks!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

From launchctl's [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) (apple seem to have misplaced  the man pages so an external one is here https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/launchctl/)

`launchctl bslist` lists "Mach bootstrap services "

To get all jobs loaded into launchctl use `sudo launchctl list`

Daemons are not necessarily the former and other things but daemons are in the list

Comment: Is it normal to get a return of well over a hundred lines when you enter "sudo launchctl list" ?

Comment: I get 328 lines

Comment: 340 here in 10.12.6 :\

Comment: I got this `Unrecognized subcommand: bslist` error. I am using Mojave

Comment: From `man launchctl` - `bslist`: _This subcommand is not implemented and has been superseded by the `print` subcommand, which provides much richer information._

Comment: The `print` subcommand will not provide an entire list of daemons. It needs an argument to provide more indepth info. Testing on macOS 11.5.1